# Why does this C++ generic function work by reference but doesn't work by value?

Tags: c++

I am new in programming world. I am facing a problem with generic function.
**T max(T arg1, U arg2)** function doesn't compile in a program. but when i change the parameter of **arg1** and **arg2** to **&agr1** and **&arg2** then the program compile with no error. The program is given below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

T max (T &arg1, T &arg2) {

    return (arg1 > arg2) ? arg1 : arg2;

};

int main() {

    int a = 12;
    int b = 24;
    cout << max(a,b) << endl;
    double x = 2.25;
    double y = .25;
    cout << max(x,y) << endl;
    string w1 = "apple";
    string w2 = "aardvark";
    cout << max(w1,w2) << endl;

    return (0);
};
```

I can't understand why this program doesn't work by value.
But another program this function work both passing value and reference. Another program is given below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U>

T max (T arg1, U arg2) {

    return (arg1 > arg2) ? arg1 : arg2;

};

int main() {

    double num1 = 35.55;
    int num2 = 130;
    cout << "Max value is: " << max(num1,num2) << endl;

    return (0);
};
```

Please help me and advance thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Try renaming `max` to something else.

Comment: I'll be gentle as it's your first day here. You're going to have to ask your question more clearly. It's currently unclear what your are asking. The two functions you present differ in more than one way. They have different template arguments *and* different argument passing schemes.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean doesn't compile. @Richard Hodges  I ask why this program shows error on compile time.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>

T max (T arg1, T arg2) {

    return (arg1 > arg2) ? arg1 : arg2;

};

int main() {

    int a = 12;
    int b = 24;
    cout << max(a,b) << endl;
    double x = 2.25;
    double y = .25;
    cout << max(x,y) << endl;
    string w1 = "apple";
    string w2 = "aardvark";
    cout << max(w1,w2) << endl;

    return (0);
};